# What's it equal to: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}\frac{1}{k\ln (n+k)}$

Tags: limits, summation

What's it equal to: 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}\frac{1}{k\ln (n+k)}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By partial summation,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k\log(n+k)}=\frac{H_n}{\log(2n)}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}H_k\left(\frac{1}{\log(n+k+1)}-\frac{1}{\log(n+k)}\right),$$
but the last term is $O\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right)$ while the limit of the first term is just $1$.

---

As an alternative, consider that
$$\frac{H_n}{\log(2n)}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k\log(n+k)}\leq \frac{H_n}{\log n}$$
is trivial, while the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k\log(n+k)}\geq\frac{H_n^2}{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\log(n+k)}{k}}=\frac{H_n^2}{H_n \log n+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(1+k/n)}{k}}.$$
It happens that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(1+k/n)}{k}\leq\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}dx=\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12},$$
so, again:
$$\left|1-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(1+k/n)}{k}\right|=O\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right).$$

Comment: It is more clear now, except of the last part with modulo, how was it obtain?